Why is it that $a < \frac{1}{a}$ is not equivalent to $a^2 < 1$?
I am trying to solve the following:
Suppose that a and b are nonzero real numbers.
Prove that if $a < \frac{1}{a} < b < \frac{1}{b}$ then $a < -1$.
Regardless of the problem, why is it that $a < \frac{1}{a}$ is not equivalent to $a^2 < 1$?
I would assume that you could multiply both sides of $a < \frac{1}{a}$ by $a$ and the resulting equation $a^2 < 1$ would be equivalent. But, graphing or plotting both equations show that they differ.

The symbol $\neq$ does not mean what perhaps you think it means. I am guessing that you are thinking of "logical equivalence", i.e. $x < \frac{1}{x}$ is not logically equivalent to $x^2 < 1$. You might want to edit your post to clarify this issue.

Let me also suggest also that, to avoid down votes and close votes, you take a look at our guidelines for how to ask a good question, with emphasis on providing context. You can easily provide some context. For example, you could edit your post to show us exactly what mathematical manipulations you have in mind for converting $x < \frac{1}{x}$ into $x^2 < 1$.

Hope these changes clarify better.

$a = -2$ satisfies the first inequality but not the second. if you multiply both sides by $a < 0$, you flip the inequality

I understand that there are cases where the inequalities are not satisfied. That's why I am confused because for many inequalities like 2 < x you would be able to manipulate using multiplication that 4 < 2x. Are you saying that this is not possible because the a that i am multiplying by may be negative which would flip the equality sign, because I think that makes sense.

If $a<b$ then you can either add to them or multiply them by a positive number. To see that multiplying by a negative changes the direction of the inequality add $-a-b$ to both sides which gives you $-b<-a$.

Voting to reopen. This is quite subtle.

If $a$ is a nonzero real number, it is either positive or negative. Inequalities often call for making case distinctions like that.
Indeed, if $a>0$, and you multiply both sides of $a < 1/a$ with $a$, you get $a^2 <1$.
But if $a<0$, and you multiply both sides of $a <1/a$ with $a$, you get $a^2 > 1$.
In each of the two cases you can simplify the inequality further. At the end you should get that:
$a < 1/a$ if and only if: either $0 <a<1$ (case of positive $a$), or $a<-1$ (case of negative $a$).

There are two issues here.
Firstly, if you multiply both sides of an inequality by a negative number, then you have to change the sign of the inequality: for example, multiply $1<2$ by $-1$ and you don't get $-1<-2$, you get $-2<-1$. So if $a<0$, then $a<1/a$ becomes $a^2>1$, not $a^2<1$.
Therefore the condition $a<1/a$ is equivalent to $a\in(-\infty,-1)\cup(0,1)$, which is definitely not the same as $a^2<1$.
Secondly, if $a>0$ and $a<1/a$, then $a<1$, so $1/a>1$. But we are given that $b<1/b$, so we know that $b<1$. Therefore if $1/a<b$, it must mean that $a<0$.
